# How to make a common text box with all validations and error handling in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an input Textbox which for which I am setting "type" from my Props. I need help in giving validation/Error Handling to this textbox as per props.
For Eg. If type=email in props, then EMail validation shall be applied to it.
Below is my current code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { runInContext } from 'vm';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const TextBox=(props)=> {
  const [type, setType] = useState('text');
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState('Enter Text');
  const [passValue, setPassValue] = useState(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    setType(props.type);
    setPlaceholder(props.placeholder);
  }, []);

  const boxClass = ["box"];
  const textContainerClassDisabled = ["textContainer"];  
  const handleChange=(e)=>{
    setPassValue(e.target.value);
  }

  const showHide=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    setType(
      type === 'input' ? 'password' : 'input'
     ) 
   };

   return (
   <div>
     {
       (type==='password' || type=== 'input') && boxClass.push('green') && 
       <p></p>
     }

    {(type==='text')&&<p></p>}
    {(type==='email')&&<p></p>}
    {
      (props.textContainerDisabled === true) && textContainerClassDisabled.push('textContainer-disabled') &&
      <p></p>   
    }

    <div class="textBoxContainer input-container">    
      <input class='textContainer'
        type={type} placeholder={placeholder} onChange={handleChange} 
        className={textContainerClassDisabled.join(' ')} disabled={props.textContainerDisabled}/>

      <span className={boxClass.join(' ')} onClick={showHide}>
        {type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
 );
}

 TextBox.defaultProps = {
  type: "text", 
  placeholder: "Enter your Text",
  boxDisabled:false
 }
 export default TextBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple library that you can use for your `react-hooks` application:
[react-hooks-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hooks-validation).

You can use other libraries instead of that. These will make the job done much easier and cleaner in your code!